# Amazon Redshift: Finding and fixing a skewed DISTKEY

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-performance, amazon-redshift

From my Redshift cluster performance panel, I can see that one of the nodes has roughly twice as much data as the others, and that leads to a significantly higher CPU utilization too. There are a few dozen large tables in the database using a key-based distribution, and I haven't been able to find which aren't properly balanced.

Searching in the documentation, I saw that the `SVV_TABLE_INFO` view has a column called `skew_rows`. Is it the number I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the "**pct_skew_across_slices**" in this article is what you're looking for.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_analyzing-table-design.html